# Target different configurations in Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm building an Ionic 4/5 Android/iOS app, and I would like to target different configurations for each environment.
For example for development environment, I want to change the app name and id and target a different provisioning profile on iOS:

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 APP_Name: 'project DEV',
 APP_Id : 'com.project.dev'
};
```

I think for that I have to change the `capacitor.config.json` and the `config.xml` files that use these variables.

I found [this solution](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic/issues/437), but I'm not familiar with gulp and I couldn't figure out how to use it.
Thanks for your help.